# How to submit values to JavaScript using two pages..?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to submit values to JavaScript using two pages "index.php" and "fonts.html".

Here is the JavaScript code that I have used in index.php:

```
<script language=javascript> 
var cp = new ColorPicker();
var fp = new FontPicker('window');

function pickFont(font) {
    document.getElementById('fimg').src='http://example.com/im/font/'   + font + '.png';
    document.getElementById('fid').value=font;
}

if (document.getElementById('fid').value) { 
    pickfont(document.getElementById('fid').value);
}
</script>
```

The values should be submitted from "fonts.html" which has the code:

```
<body>
     <p><form method=get action="/fonts.html" style="display:inline"><input     type=submit     name=cat value="Favorites"></form>
     <div id="Favorites">
              <A HREF="#"   onClick="window.opener.FontPicker_pickFont(Times-Roman,window); return  false;"     STYLE="text-decoration:none;"><img alt="Times-Roman "   style="border: outset 1pt"  border=1 vspace=1 hspace=1      src="http://www.example.com/im/font/Times-Roman.png"></a>
 <A HREF="#" onClick="window.opener.FontPicker_pickFont(ariel,window);  return false;" STYLE="text-decoration:none;"><img alt="ariel " style="border:   outset 1pt"     border=1 vspace=1 hspace=1  src="http://www.example.com/im/font/font/ariel.png"></a>
 </div>             
</body>
```

When user opens index.php they will get a link; when they click on the link they will be redirected to "fonts.html" where they gets an option to click on one of images "Times-Roman.png" and "ariel.png" .

Now what I am trying to do two things:

1. when the user clicks on "Times-Roman.png".  '('fimg').src'  should get the location of "Times-Roman.png"

and

2. `('fid').value` should hold the value "Times-Roman.ttf"

I know this can be implemented by adding JavaScript code in the second page "fonts.html" but  not exactly getting the code. Your response much appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

font value you are passing to `pickfont` needs to be a string, you are treating as variable

Comment: can u please corect that code?and write a new one that works?

Comment: hi charlietfl.. i tried by correcting window.opener.FontPicker_pickFont('Times-Roman',window) but no go.. same problem....not fixed

Comment: use a browser console to look at errors...Firebug or chrome (f12)

Comment: but i dont find any errors.. check out the demo page [link](http://srihost.com/im/1.php) then click on "pick" next to font it takes you to [link](http://srihost.com/im/fonts.html)  .. then select the first image that is "srinivas" it will redirect back to index.html... where "srinivas" image needs to be selected next to font. hope u got an idea now???

Comment: document.getElementById("fid") is null  right on page load, can't look for something before it exists

Comment: I really appreciate your response  charlietfl .. but how to correct document.getElementById("fid")  ????can u please guide me with correct code?

Comment: can't search the DOM until elements exist, read up on load events

Comment: thanks alot for reponses charlietfl but where should i need to add element? in fonts.html ?please checkout [link](http://mklogo.com) he has used the same technique ...i have given you the full source code.. is it possible for you  to corrrect??